# How Can I embed java3d's Canvas3d in javafx layout?

Tags: java, swing, javafx, java-3d

I try to embed `Canvas3d` in `StackPane` using `SwingNode`.
I put `Canvas3d` into `JPanel`, and put `JPanel` into `SwingNode`. But only empty `Jpanel` was appeared.
I heard in somewhere that `SwingNode` is rendering only pure Swing. So I used `JCanvas3d` instead of `Canvas3d`, but it is not working too! 
Is there any method to embed Java3d's `Canvas3d` in javafx layout? It's okay if not use SwingNode.

My java version is jdk 1.8_xx And Here is my source code

```
public class Main extends Application
{
public static void main( String[] args )
{
    launch( args );
}

@Override
public void start( Stage primaryStage )
{

    try
    {

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        SwingNode swingNode = new SwingNode();

        root.setPrefSize( 400, 400 );
        root.setMinSize( 400, 400 );

        Scene scene = new Scene( root, 400, 400 );
        primaryStage.setScene( scene );
        primaryStage.show();
        root.setPrefSize( 400, 400 );

        root.getChildren().add( swingNode );

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater( new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {

                GraphicsConfiguration config = SimpleUniverse.getPreferredConfiguration();
                Canvas3D canvas = new Canvas3D( config );

                SimpleUniverse univ = new SimpleUniverse( canvas );
                univ.getViewingPlatform().setNominalViewingTransform();
                BranchGroup scene = createSceneGraph();
                scene.compile();
                univ.addBranchGraph( scene );

                JPanel panel = new JPanel();
                panel.add( canvas );

                swingNode.setContent( panel );

            }
        } );

    }
    catch ( Exception e )
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public BranchGroup createSceneGraph()
{
    BranchGroup branch = new BranchGroup();

    // Make a changeable 3D transform
    TransformGroup trans = new TransformGroup();
    trans.setCapability( TransformGroup.ALLOW_TRANSFORM_WRITE );
    branch.addChild( trans );

    // Make a shape
    ColorCube demo = new ColorCube( 0.4 );
    trans.addChild( demo );

    // Make a behavor to spin the shape
    Alpha spinAlpha = new Alpha( -1, 4000 );
    RotationInterpolator spinner = new RotationInterpolator( spinAlpha, trans );
    spinner.setSchedulingBounds( new BoundingSphere( new Point3d(), 1000.0 ) );
    trans.addChild( spinner );

    return branch;
}
}
```

Comment: [JavaFX has built in 3D support](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/graphics-tutorial/javafx-3d-graphics.htm), why would you try to embed Java3D?

Comment: @jewelsea Because I want to put project which made of java3d into javaFX project.

Comment: `JPanel panel = new JPanel();` Will default to `FlowLayout`, Try instead `.. new JPanel(new GridLayout);` which will fill the available space with whatever component is added to the panel.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Not working. I think it's not matter what is JPanel's layout

Comment: *"I think it's not matter what is JPanel's layout"* There is *no accounting* for what people think. For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).