# How to embed a Canvas3D in a JavaFX application?

Tags: java, swing, javafx, javafx-8, java-3d

I'm developing a JavaFX desktop application. In it I want to display some java 3D objects.

The way to do this, as far as I know, is using JavaFX's SwingNode. Java 3d has to be integrated in a Swing component too. So it's a two-step process.

**Integrating Java 3D objects with Java Swing**

Complete and minimal example composed of the panel I intend to reuse in the FX app and a JFrame that shows it works:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class JFrameWithCanvas3D extends JFrame {
   public JFrameWithCanvas3D() {
      super("Swing JFrame Wraps Canvas3D");
      setLayout(new BorderLayout());

      BallPanel panel = new BallPanel();
      add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
      setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      pack();
      setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      System.setProperty("sun.awt.noerasebackground", "true");
      javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         @SuppressWarnings("unused")
         @Override
         public void run() {
            new JFrameWithCanvas3D();
         }
      });
   }  
}

public class BallPanel extends JPanel {

   public BallPanel() {
      setLayout(new BorderLayout());
      setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
      add(makeCanvas());

   }

   private static Canvas3D makeCanvas() {
      BranchGroup group = new BranchGroup();
      group.addChild(makeLight());
      group.addChild(new Sphere(5));

      Canvas3D canvas3D = new Canvas3D(SimpleUniverse.getPreferredConfiguration());
      SimpleUniverse universe = new SimpleUniverse(canvas3D);
      Transform3D viewTransform = new Transform3D();
      viewTransform.setTranslation(new Vector3d(0, 0, 20)); //move "back" a little
      universe.getViewingPlatform().getViewPlatformTransform().setTransform(viewTransform);
      universe.addBranchGraph(group);
      return canvas3D;
   }

   private static DirectionalLight makeLight() {
      DirectionalLight light = new DirectionalLight(new Color3f(Color.WHITE), new Vector3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f));
      light.setInfluencingBounds(new BoundingSphere(new Point3d(0, 0, 0), 100));
      return light;
   }

}
```

**Integrating the BallPanel in the JavaFX app**

```
public class FXAppWithSwingPanel extends Application {
   @Override
   public void start(Stage stage) {
       final SwingNode swingNode = new SwingNode();

       JPanel panel = new JPanel();       
       panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
       panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(450, 450));
       panel.add(new BallPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
       swingNode.setContent(panel);

       Pane pane = new Pane();
       pane.getChildren().add(swingNode);

       stage.setScene(new Scene(pane, 500, 500));
       stage.show();
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       launch(args);
   }

}
```

All I see is a gray background where the sphere should be. I've tried a few different variations with no luck. Couldn't find anything online about this particular integration between Java 3D classes and JavaFX.

I know JavaFX has 3D graphics but I don't like them (at all).

Related, unresolved, question:

[How Can I embed java3d's Canvas3d in javafx layout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35053596/how-can-i-embed-java3ds-canvas3d-in-javafx-layout)

Comment: I don't know Java-3D. Is the `Canvas3D` a lightweight component (i.e. one that is rendered by Swing, not by the native windowing toolkit)? If not, you will not be able to render it in a `SwingNode`. Also note you should create the content for the `SwingNode` on the AWT event dispatch thread via `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(...)`: see the [`SwingNode` docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/embed/swing/SwingNode.html).

Comment: Ah, that could be it. Apparently Canvas3D is a heavyweight GUI element. Any workaround?

Comment: I don't think so. `SwingNode` is designed for back-compatibility with "pure swing" components (i.e. lightweight components), but JavaFX in general was designed from scratch. You probably have to use JavaFX 3D if you're using JavaFX. If you want to go the JavaFX route, José Pereda (who posts here sometimes) is probably the person to look to for good JavaFX 3d articles.

Comment: Thanks. Post it as a reply if you want and if no one suggest another solution I'll mark it as answered in a few days.

Comment: I'll hold off a while as I'm not much of an expert on 3D in general; if no-one has a better suggestion later I'll just summarize these comments in an answer.

Comment: Have you tried com.sun.j3d.exp.swing.JCanvas3D? http://jogamp.org/deployment/java3d/1.6.0-final/javadoc/com/sun/j3d/exp/swing/JCanvas3D.html OpenJFX/JavaFX doesn't interoperate well with third party 3D APIs in general, I explained why here: https://jogamp.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=607

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally managed to make it work using JCanvas3D. Credit for the suggestion goes to @gouessej. Many thanks.

Here is the new `makeCanvas` method:

```
   private void makeCanvas() {
      GraphicsConfigTemplate3D gCT = new GraphicsConfigTemplate3D();
      JCanvas3D jCanvas3D = new JCanvas3D(gCT);
      Dimension canvasDim = new Dimension(400, 400);
      jCanvas3D.setPreferredSize(canvasDim);
      jCanvas3D.setSize(canvasDim);
      add(jCanvas3D, BorderLayout.CENTER);          
      Canvas3D canvas3D =  jCanvas3D.getOffscreenCanvas3D(); 

      View view = new View();
      view.setPhysicalBody(new PhysicalBody());
      view.setPhysicalEnvironment(new PhysicalEnvironment());
      view.addCanvas3D(canvas3D);

      ViewPlatform vp = new ViewPlatform();
      view.attachViewPlatform(vp);


      Transform3D viewTransform = new Transform3D();
      viewTransform.setTranslation(new Vector3d(0, 0, 20)); //move "back" a little

      TransformGroup viewTG = new TransformGroup();
      viewTG.setCapability(TransformGroup.ALLOW_TRANSFORM_WRITE);
      viewTG.setTransform(viewTransform);

      viewTG.addChild(vp);


      viewTG.addChild(makeLight());
      viewTG.addChild(new Sphere(5));

      BranchGroup group = new BranchGroup();
      group.addChild(viewTG);
      group.addChild(makeLight());
      group.addChild(new Sphere(5));

      VirtualUniverse vu = new VirtualUniverse();
      Locale locale = new Locale(vu);  
      locale.addBranchGraph(group);
   }
```

Also, as James_D points out in the comments, `Canvas3D` was not the way to go as it cannot be correctly rendered in a `JavaFX` `SwingNode` because it is a heavyweight component.

The [SwingNode javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/embed/swing/SwingNode.html) confirms it:

> The hierarchy of components contained in the JComponent instance
>   should not contain any heavyweight components, otherwise SwingNode may
>   fail to paint it.

Answer (score 0):

If these two sentences "I'm developing a JavaFX desktop application. In it I want to display some java 3D objects." are really the essence of what you are asking here, then you are completely on the wrong track. JavaFX supports 3D shapes natively, so unless you have very specific requirements there is no need for any Canvas3D and embedding any Swing.

I just see that you have said that you know the JavaFX 3D graphics but you don't like it. Could you be a bit more specific about what you don't like?

Comment: Sure: 1. Looks very ugly by default and without lots of tweaking 2. javafx 3d api lacks high level functions that can be found in j3d (could be wrong about this, it was my impression when I tried to do rotations and whatnot) 3. I don't like the api, too complex 4. Something very specific to my application having to do with two sided surfaces, wherein sets of duplicate surfaces won't display correctly. This must be a javafx defect. I can't properly explain in this limited space. This was the deal breaker.